# C# Convert date (day-Month-year) to MM/dd/yyy Error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am reading a date from a csv which has date in format "8-Mar-18". I am using DateTime.ParseExtract to convert it to date format "MM/dd/yyyy" but I am getting error as

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is a repro:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime.ParseExact("8-Mar-18", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How do I convert it to MM/dd/yyy ?

Thanks all.

Comment: "8-Mar-18"  is **not**  "MM/dd/yyyy" is it?  Further. dates do not have a format so this may all be for nought

Comment: If you want to parse a string into a DateTime use the *correct* format string. The result will be a DateTime object which does *not* have any format. It's a binary value

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("8-Mar-18",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` works just fine. It returns a DateTime object whose value is March 8, 2018. Formatting applies only during parsing or generating strings. If you want to display a DateTime in a certain way use a format string, or the set the appropriate `Format` property in whatever control or UI element you use to display it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a two step process.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("8-Mar-18", "d-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: That generates a string, not a DateTime. DateTime has no format. `DateTime.Parse("8-Mar-18", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` would work just as well, there's no reason to use `ParseExact`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done on one line.

```
var s = DateTime.ParseExact("8-Mar-18", "d-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```